# Emacs, searching for something that is seperated by a newline

Tags: regex, emacs

I have some data files that end up having pesky erroneous lines. For example, in the following file:

```
data, A, 1, B, 2
,
,
,
,
,
data, A, 4, B,5
```

I want to get rid of the five comma only lines. What search string do I enter into emacs to find these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
M-x flush-lines RET ^,$ RET
```

where `RET` means hit Return(or Enter) key.
You can read [this page](http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/removing-blank-lines-buffer) for more detail.